# Temporarily remove item from list

Tags: python, list, bots, telegram

I want to remove an item from a list temporarily and add it back after x hours. `sleep` is not an option for me as I want the code to continue running and not halt.

Being new to Python, I am playing around with threads and I can get it to work with a couple minor bugs.

P.S. The reason I want to remove item from a list for x hours is; I get a `floodError` after adding x amount of users to a group on using a Telegram bot. My code iterates through a list of accounts I own, and if one account gives me the error, I want it out of the list for 5 hours.

Anyway, here is my code, for this approach, how do I stop the specific thread after the `add_account` has run once?

I'd appreciate a *better* approach on this as well please.

```
import threading

accounts = [ {"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5} ]
break_accounts = []

PING_ON = threading.Event()


def remove_account(account):

    break_accounts.append(account)
    accounts.remove(account)
    print(accounts)
    print(break_accounts)
    t = threading.Thread(target=add_account(account))
    t.start()

    PING_ON.set()

def add_account(account):
    while not PING_ON.wait(20):

        break_accounts.remove(account)
        accounts.append(account)
        print(accounts)
        print(break_accounts)



def start():
    for account in accounts:
        if account["id"] == 4:
            remove_account(account)


start()
```

Comment: move item to other list and add it back from this list later.

Comment: By adding back to initial list later, do you mean I've got to add a loop to get me the time for every account that is removed from the list?

Comment: you have to use `time` in loop to check if it is time to put it back. On List you can put item with time when it has to go back to main list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on unnecessarily shaky ground here using Threads.  Unnecessary for this, esp. if you are new to Python.

Before that, your accounts list-dictionary is odd.  Just make a dictionary of accounts with the ID as key.  (See mine below.)  It isn't clear why you made unnecessary dictionaries in a list.

I'd recommend using built in datetime and timedelta to do this.  You could assign active times for each account and check it vs. the system clock which is accessible.

Here is an idea below.  There are several possible variants of this... the basic premise is to keep a marker for each account, update it from current time when required, and check it before you do something with the account

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

accounts = {'id_1': 100, 'id_2': 205, 'id_3': 310}

# make dictionary of reactivate times for all id's using minimum value (active at start)
reactiveate_times = {id: datetime.min for id in accounts}

def suspend(id, reactiveate_times, suspension_minutes=1):
    reactiveate_times[id] = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=suspension_minutes)


suspend('id_2', reactiveate_times)

for t in range(5):    # run the loop 5 x 20 sec (100 seconds) to see acct 2 reactivate
    print(f'at time {datetime.now()} these accounts are active:')
    for id in accounts:
        if datetime.now() > reactiveate_times.get(id):
            print(f'  account {id} is active!')

    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply! The dictionary I used on here is just an example. I have yet to try the code you gave me, but wouldn't `time.sleep(20)` cause the entire program to halt? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Could you have a look at this code and tell me why function 1 and 2 run the second time and how I would fix this please? https://www.onlinegdb.com/HJWrYiWgU

Comment: I only put time.sleep() in the example to simulate the passage of time to show that account 2 is "suspended" for 1 minute.  I have no idea how you are managing the flow of time in your actual code...you mentioned that you wanted something to happen for 5 hours, so you could change the timedelta to hours and go for it.

Comment: I can't figure out what's going on with the code you linked to.  I'm not proficient at threading issues.